# chat history download into local system

Tags: chatter, community

How can i download the chat history of last week data into my local system. May i know is it possible or not.? if means any suggestions plz.

for this i have to write a any query. or i have to do any modifications. in my admin account,

Actually i want to download the chat history between the two users may i know how can i possible, we are using enterprise edition.both users are in the chatter profile.

Comment: Sathya, can you please clarify? You're talking about the "Chat" window (bottom-right corner of most pages when SF is accessed as webpage) or about a history of Chatter posts by users that are related to them, to some records or maybe just `@mentions`?

Comment: @eyescream actually we are using desktop chatter, one of my users wants to download the chat history, that means he chat with another user, he wants to download the chat history between him and another user.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to view a chat that you aren't a participant in. Real-time chat messages are not exposed in any of the APIs. You can only view the recent chat history through the UI if you were involved in the chat.

Comment: @Aliuoe i think salesforce have to rectify this problem, why because in skype we can download all previous months history,      but our company uses salesforce desktop chatter,

Comment: You can view your chat history in the web UI from the past 72 hours and I suppose you could copy & paste it to get it on your local system. But there isn't a more convenient way to do it for a longer time period like Skype. See https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_chat_history.htm&language=en_US#collab_chat_history for more info.